# Comparing doubles using '=='

Tags: c++, double, comparison, precision

I wrote the binary search code below:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool check(vector<int>& dist, double hour, int mid) {
        if(mid==0) return false;
        
        double sum=0.0;
        for(int i=0; i<dist.size()-1; i++)
            sum+=ceil((double)dist[i]/mid);
        sum+=(double)dist.back()/mid;
        
        return sum<=hour ? true : false;
        // sum+=0.001f;
        // return sum<hour || std::fabs(hour-sum)<=0.001f ? true : false;
    }
    
    int minSpeedOnTime(vector<int>& dist, double hour) {
        int l=0, r=10000001;
        
        while(l<r) {
            int mid=l+(r-l)/2;
            if(check(dist, hour, mid)) {
                r=mid;
            } else l=mid+1;
        }
        
        return r==10000001 ? -1 : r;
    }
};
```

It works and gets "accepted", but I had few questions:

a. Is the statement `return sum<=hour ? true : false;` correct?  I am unsure because both `sum` and `hour` are `double`s.  Shouldn't we be using some 'epsilon' for '==' comparison, like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)? 
b. If uncommented, the following statement:

> return sum<hour || std::fabs(hour-sum)<=0.001f ? true : false;

yields an incorrect answer.  Why? The problem statement says that "hour will have at most two digits after decimal".  So why does it give a wrong answer?
c. It gets accepted, if I add `0.001f`:

```cpp
sum+=0.001f;
return sum<hour || std::fabs(hour-sum)<=0.001f ? true : false;
```

Again, why?
**Edit**: Even `std::fabs(hour-sum)==0.001f` above doesn't get accepted.

**Edit2**: The problem statement is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-speed-to-arrive-on-time/), but I am not asking about the solution, etc., so I have not posted it in the question.

Comment: You're *already* not comparing with `==` but with `<=`, so any perceived problem with `==` doesn't apply.

Comment: @EOF, sorry, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @EOF `f1 <= f2` is the same as `f1 < f2 || f1 == f2` and if the epsilon is symmetric then `f1` could be slightly greater than `f2` and should still test equal.  So the problem with `==` does apply.

Comment: @Someone have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You should not cargo cult with floating point.

Comment: @RichardCritten, are you suggesting I try `return sum<hour || std::fabs(hour-sum)==0.001f` instead, with that example? (equals instead of <=).

Comment: two significant digits does not imply that adding `0.001f` would not change the result. Significant digits of `double x = 0.009` are `0.00` but significant digits of `x + 0.001f` are `0.01`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, could you please elaborate?  Also, please note that it gives correct answer on adding `0.001f`.

Comment: The better equivalence to `a <= b` is  `!(b < a)`.

Comment: The other potential problem with `double` is that it could be NaN, or +Inf, or -Inf.  If the data set doesn't contain those, then problem avoided.  Otherwise some consideration for how those are to be handled.

Comment: `0.009` is one example of adding `0.001f` changing the significant digits, which can make the difference between correct and not correct results here. Thats all I was saying. Your assumption that you can add `0.001f` because only two digits matter is not correct

Comment: @Eljay, that's a good point.  The problem statement does say: `1 <= hour <= 10^9`, so `NaN`, `+Inf` and `-Inf` are avoided.

Answer (score 1):

> Comparing doubles using '=='

This is a case where floating point should not even be used or at least greatly reduced.

Example with nary a rounding issue.

```
bool check(vector<int>& dist, double hour, int mid) {
    long long sum_times_mid = dist.back();
    for(int i=0; i<dist.size()-1; i++) {
        sum_times_mid += dist[i];
    }
    return sum_times_mid <= hour*mid;  // Only FP code here
}
```

Comment: Good writing with a broad vocabulary is a narrow slice of what is penned -- but there is hope. Fully explained in six words. Well played ... again.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that `long long` is an integer type, so what makes comparing with `hour*mid` (a double?) valid?  Besides, if both are double (via typecasting), then would we get the right answer when `sum_times_mid==hour*mid`?  Also, I submitted with your `check()` but got a wrong answer for this test case: `[1,1,100000] 2.01`.  Output is: `49753` while Expected is: `10000000`.

Comment: Is it just me, or is this the most convoluted way to write `auto sum_times_mid = std::accumulate(dist.cbegin(), dist.cend(), long long(0));`?